# Add a horizontal scrollbar to a chart using HTML

Tags: html

I am working on vb.net application which deals with results displayed in charts. I am looking to add a scrollbar to the X-axis of the chart since there are many results to show on x-axis. Due to more number of records, the bar lines of the chart shrinks and ultimately looks ugly and unreadable. I am attaching the existing HTML for reference. Please let me know how to add a scrollbar here.

**HTML Syntax:**

```
<div style="width: 1102px">
<asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<asp:Chart ID="chtCompletion" runat="server" ImageLocation="TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" Width="1000" Palette="SeaGreen" > 
   <Series> 
      <asp:Series Name="Completions" ChartType="Column"  ChartArea="MainChartArea"> 
        </asp:Series> 
   </Series> 

   <ChartAreas> 
      <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea" > 
      <AxisX Title="Clients Filenumber" Interval="1"></AxisX>
      <AxisY Title="Completion %" Interval="25" Maximum="100"></AxisY>
      </asp:ChartArea> 
   </ChartAreas> 
</asp:Chart> 
</div>
```

Comment: As alternative to what Shomz said (in case you want to keep chart with its size but you want to scroll its content, for example to keep axis visible) just check [ScaleView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.scaleview(v=vs.110).aspx) property for X [Axis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis(v=vs.110).aspx). Bind `ViewMinimum` and `ViewMaximum` to an _external_ HTML range control and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to display a scrollbar using the below code:

```
<div id="wrap" style="width:700px; height:325px; overflow-x: scroll;"> 
    <asp:Chart ID="chtCompletion" runat="server" Width="1500px" 
        Palette="SeaGreen" Height="298px">
```

I used "wrap" property in my  and increased my chart width to accomodate as much data as I would need. This works!! Thanks for the help guys... :)

Cheers,
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

Adding a width to your chart element (you might have to calculate it if your chart is dynamic) and, if needed, use `overflow-x: auto` on it.

Comment: Hi Shomz, I tried to add the overflow-x: auto here and it says overflow-x: auto is not a known css property!

Comment: However I can see the scrollbars when I use overflow: auto. But I need to put the scrollbar on x-axis and not on y-axis. In my case, scrollbar on the y-axis is enabled but I have no use for that scrollbar. My issue is the x-axis data which needs a scrollbar. But using overflow: auto sets a disabled scrollbar on x-axis and all my bar lines still continue to shrink to occupy excess records :(

Comment: Hi, hmm, sounds like you're putting the overflow on a wrong element, try experimenting with which element you put it on. Here is a super simple example of what my original answer was about: http://jsfiddle.net/v12pgbe1/ And you can see `overflow-x` does work, not sure why it doesn't work for you.